# Replace pages at-least 100 in PDF from another PDF

Tags: python, pdf

**This is an example of code,**

```
import PyPDF2
import numpy as np
# creating a pdf file object
pdfFileObj = open('original.pdf' , 'rb')

pdfFileObj_1 = open('tutorial.pdf', 'rb')
# creating a pdf reader object
pdfReader = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(pdfFileObj)
pdfReader_1 = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(pdfFileObj_1)
# creating a pdf writer object for new pdf
pdfWriter = PyPDF2.PdfFileWriter()
for i in range(100):
    page= pdfReader.getPage(i)
    page_1= pdfReader_1.getPage(i)
    pdfWriter.addPage(page)
    pdfWriter.addPage(page_1)

#print(pdfWriter.getNumPages())
# new pdf file object
newFile = open('replaced_pdf_1.pdf', 'wb')


pdfWriter.write(newFile)

# closing the original pdf file object
pdfFileObj.close()
pdfFileObj_1.close()
# closing the new pdf file object
newFile.close()
```

**And the error i got,**

> PdfReadWarning: Object 321 0 not defined. [pdf.py:1629] Traceback
>   (most recent call last):   File "test.py", line 22, in 
>       pdfWriter.write(newFile)   File "/home/ubuntu/Ritesh/working/lib/python3.5/site-packages/PyPDF2/pdf.py",
>   line 482, in write
>       self._sweepIndirectReferences(externalReferenceMap, self._root)   File
>   "/home/ubuntu/Ritesh/working/lib/python3.5/site-packages/PyPDF2/pdf.py",
>   line 571, in _sweepIndirectReferences
>       self._sweepIndirectReferences(externMap, realdata)   File "/home/ubuntu/Ritesh/working/lib/python3.5/site-packages/PyPDF2/pdf.py",
>   line 547, in _sweepIndirectReferences
>       value = self._sweepIndirectReferences(externMap, value)   File "/home/ubuntu/Ritesh/working/lib/python3.5/site-packages/PyPDF2/pdf.py",
>   line 571, in _sweepIndirectReferences
>       self._sweepIndirectReferences(externMap, realdata)   File "/home/ubuntu/Ritesh/working/lib/python3.5/site-packages/PyPDF2/pdf.py",
>   line 547, in _sweepIndirectReferences
>       value = self._sweepIndirectReferences(externMap, value)   File "/home/ubuntu/Ritesh/working/lib/python3.5/site-packages/PyPDF2/pdf.py",
>   line 556, in _sweepIndirectReferences
>       value = self._sweepIndirectReferences(externMap, data[i])   File "/home/ubuntu/Ritesh/working/lib/python3.5/site-packages/PyPDF2/pdf.py",
>   line 571, in _sweepIndirectReferences
>       self._sweepIndirectReferences(externMap, realdata)   File "/home/ubuntu/Ritesh/working/lib/python3.5/site-packages/PyPDF2/pdf.py",
>   line 547, in _sweepIndirectReferences
>       value = self._sweepIndirectReferences(externMap, value)   File "/home/ubuntu/Ritesh/working/lib/python3.5/site-packages/PyPDF2/pdf.py",
>   line 577, in _sweepIndirectReferences
>       newobj = data.pdf.getObject(data)   File "/home/ubuntu/Ritesh/working/lib/python3.5/site-packages/PyPDF2/pdf.py",
>   line 1631, in getObject
>       raise utils.PdfReadError("Could not find object.") PyPDF2.utils.PdfReadError: Could not find object.

What i understood from changing the number of pages added to the `PdfFileWriter` object `pdfWriter`..if the pages are more than around 5 it showing above error..else its working fine. I need to replce pages more than 100..please anyone help with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used this sample code on Windows 10 and Red Hat Enterprise Linux 6.
On both platforms I used python 2.7 (I don't have python 3.5 on my workstation).
As you didn't provide your versions of original.pdf and tutorial.pdf, I used 2 e-books in pdf format: 686 pages and 1014 pages respectively.

And I could not confirm your observations: with

for i in range(100):

replaced with

for i in range(600):

I received 1200-paged output pdf.